# If $f(x)$ is a continuous function in the interval $[a,b]$ then prove that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \ge \min_{x \in [a, b]}f(x) \cdot(b-a)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> If $f(x)$ is a continuous function in the interval $[a,b]$  and if $f(x)$ is minimized in that interval at $x=c$, then prove that  $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \ge f(c)(b-a)$.

[image]

I know this is true if refer to the graph of $f(x)$ because the area shaded in orange will always be less than or equal to the area marked in green but I want to prove without using graphs. I am using this result in the proof of another problem so it would be helpful if someone can suggest a formal way to prove it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not true, you forgot the $(b-a)$ factor, and you either need to reverse the inequality or take the maximum of $f$

Comment: ... and it should be $\ge$.

Comment: Just try taking difference of LHS and RHS.

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, dx\ge \int_a^b f(c) \,dx =  f(c)(b-a)$

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. That's just what I needed. I don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\ {\mathrm d}}$As Martin has already pointed out, we have $$\int_a^b f(x) \d x \geqslant \int_a^b f(c) \d x = f(c)(b - a).$$

---

Here's something more which is true: There actually exists some $\xi \in (a, b)$ such that $$\frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f(x) \d x = f(\xi).$$
You can interpret this as a "Mean value theorem" for integrals. In fact, the proof is pretty much just that. Consider the function $F : [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ defined as $$F(x) := \int_a^x f(t) \d t.$$
Since $f$ is continuous, $F$ is differentiable with $F' = f$. Moreover, the usual mean value theorem tells us that there exists $\xi \in (a, b)$ such that $$f(\xi) = F'(\xi) \overset{\rm MVT}{=} \frac{F(b) - F(a)}{b - a} = \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f(x) \d x.$$
Of course, since $f(\xi) \geqslant \min_{x \in [a, b]} f(x)$, your result follows.

---

**Remark.** Continuity is necessary for the result above. Otherwise, consider $f$ to be the floor function on $[0, 2]$. This is integrable with "mean" equal to $\frac12$ which is never attained by $f$.

However, the result you're asking for remains true even without the assumption of continuity. (Of course, we would have to impose the bare minimum conditions that the function be integrable and attain a minimum.)

Comment: The floor function on $[0,2]$ does not take value of $1/2$?

Comment: @Ilya: correct. It takes the value $0$ on $[0, 1)$, the value $1$ on $[1, 2)$ and the value $2$ on $\{2\}$.

Comment: Sure, confused it with the fractional part for some reason.